# How can i create a function that removes a div when I push a link?

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner coder. Could someone help me make it so that when I press on an exit link the html that I injected before disappears?

```js
const btnif = document.querySelector("#ytif");
const ifpss = document.querySelector(".ifpss");

btnif.addEventListener('click', () => {
  ifpss.innerHTML = `<div class="ytifrore"><div class="ytiframe"><div 
  id="closep"> &times;
  Fermer la page </div><iframe class="ytifr" width="1280" 
  height="720"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KMPkI"
  title="YouTube video 
  player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer;  autoplay;  clipboard - write;
  encrypted - media; gyroscope;
  picture - in -picture " allowfullscreen></iframe></div></div>`;
})
```

```html
<div class="ifpss"></div>
<a href="#" id="ytif" class="watch-more buttontext">
  <p>Voir la vidéo de présentation &rarr;</p>
</a>
```

Comment: On the click handler for your link, call `ifpss.innerHTML = ''`

Comment: Note that I converted your HTML string to a template literal using backticks instead of quotes. Huge lines of code aren't fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `<a href="#" onclick="ifpss.innerHTML=''">` to make the text a link that deletes the `ifpss` html.

```js
const btnif = document.querySelector("#ytif");
const ifpss = document.querySelector(".ifpss");

btnif.addEventListener('click', () => {
  ifpss.innerHTML = `<div class="ytifrore"><div class="ytiframe"><div 
  id="closep"> <a href="#" onclick="ifpss.innerHTML=''">&times;
  Fermer la page</a> </div><iframe class="ytifr" width="1280" 
  height="720"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KMPkI"
  title="YouTube video 
  player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer;  autoplay;  clipboard - write;
  encrypted - media; gyroscope;
  picture - in -picture " allowfullscreen></iframe></div></div>`;
})
```

```html
<div class="ifpss"></div>
<a href="#" id="ytif" class="watch-more buttontext">
  <p>Voir la vidéo de présentation &rarr;</p>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
var myobj = document.getElementById("demo");
myobj.remove();
```

could help

Have a look at https://www.w3schools.com  there are good examples for beginners

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put your link inside the target div? Then it'll be naturally overwritten by your existing code.

```js
const btnif = document.querySelector("#ytif");
const ifpss = document.querySelector(".ifpss");

btnif.addEventListener('click', () => {
  ifpss.innerHTML = `<div class="ytifrore"><div class="ytiframe"><div 
  id="closep"> &times;
  Fermer la page </div><iframe class="ytifr" width="1280" 
  height="720"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KMPkI"
  title="YouTube video 
  player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer;  autoplay;  clipboard - write;
  encrypted - media; gyroscope;
  picture - in -picture " allowfullscreen></iframe></div></div>`;
})
```

```html
<div class="ifpss">
  <a href="#" id="ytif" class="watch-more buttontext">
    <p>Voir la vidéo de présentation &rarr;</p>
  </a>
</div>
```